# jQuery - DOM manipulation of element without affecting subelemnt

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-traversal

I am trying to make some kind of a pseudo-breadcrumb - or a title that is based on the name of the current file ( path ) .

So I wrote a function like so :

```
function getPageName(){

    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );

    // reverse array give the last one. easier to keep track in URls
    var pathLast = pathArray.reverse()[0]; 

    return pathLast;

    }
```

My markup is as followed ( note - the markup can not be changed / amended / fixed - so no new classes spans or IDs can be added ) :

```
    <h3 class="page-title">

   First Path <small>Sub Path</small>

    </h3>
```

Changing the area of `Sub Path` proves easy :

```
var pathLast = getPageName();
jQuery("h3.page-title small").html(pathLast);
```

But I can not seem to find how to target the `First Path` ...

I tried

```
jQuery("h3.page-title small").before().html(pathLast);
```

But - of course it changes the whole `h3` - thus deleting the subpath.

I even tried :

```
var currentMenuItemx = jQuery("a[href='" + pathLast + "']").parent().parent().parent().find('span[class="title"]');
 jQuery("h3.page-title small").before(currentMenuItemx).html(pathLast);
```

which proves equally useless  .

I also tried along the lines of :

```
// var title = currentMenuItemParent.get(0)+ "<small>"+pathLast+"<small>";
```

Not working for me.

so my question is how to target and change an element that has another element inside without affecting the subelement.

**UPDATE** :

@Terwanerik approach would work ( similar to my last example - but sharper jQUery skills )

..BUT

The function would have to change a bit to :

function getPageName(){

```
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );

    // reverse array give the last one. easier to keep track in URls
    var pathLast = pathArray.reverse(); // return whole array

    return pathLast;

    }
```

Thus returning the whole array ..
Otherwise , the result for index.php for example is ( string) :

```
    <h3 class="page-title">

   i<small>n</small>

    </h3>
```

But still - I guess what I really wanted to know is if there is some jQuery function to handle those situations in general , since `parent()` nor `before()` seems to be right for this case ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just changing all the html in the `<h3 class='page-title'>` like so:

```
jQuery("h3.page-title").html(pathLast[0]+"<small>"+pathLast[1]+"</small>");
```

Comment: +1 This is the right direction. see update . I also edited your answer ( `pathLast`, not `pathList`) .

Answer (score 1):

You could try filtering with the [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) function:

```
$("h3").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 3; }).first().replaceWith("Changed Path");
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/03ubwLwk/)**

Comment: This is great .. A bit complicated for my skills, but seems great. I do not know neither the `filter()` nor the `contents()`. Will try to investigate now because I would like an approach that can easily be applied in other similar situations ..

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question.

You don't want to know how to target and change an element that has another element inside without affecting the subelement.

what you want to do is be told that you shouldn't set your breadcrumbs up like that - it's a poor way of doing it. Instead, you should set them up as a list which you can then target (and style via CSS) much more easily:

```
<ul id="breadcrumbs">
    <li>First Path</li>
    <li>Sub Path</li>
</ul>
```

Now you can target specific parts of the path with

```
$('#breadcrumbs').find('li')[ 3 ] // for the 4th <li>
```

which is a much easier way to deal with it.

You can also use CSS to add separators between them (`:before` selector, `content:` attribute and `li + li` selector) far easier, and much more semantically.

Comment: You are right . But as I wrote - I can not change the markup structure at all. ( I can also not explain the whole project now . Just take it as a fact )

Comment: That's fair enough. I'll leave this here anyway, and if it gets downvoted then it happens. I think it's useful general information :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can target the `.children()` of the `h3` then get their `.outerHTML()` to get all the HTML to recreate them. That lets you modify the base textual content of the parent tag without worrying about anything else to do with the children:

```
$('h3.page-title').html( 'New Page' + $('h3.page-title').children().outerHTML() );
```

You would of course lose any context for the tags, if they're interspersed with plain text nodes:

```
<h3>
    Something
    <b>Bold</b>
    Else (this disappears)
    <i>Italics</i>
</h3>
```

but for your use-case it should work without any problem.